# Подскажите в чем разница между записями

Tags: php, laravel

Прошу помощи. php8, laravel8. Не могу понять в чем разница записей. Мой уровень ниже джуна, учусь.

1. `$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();`
2. `$user = Auth::user();`

пользователь авторизован. В дампе получаю один и тот же объект в обоих случаях.
в первом случае всё работает корректно, хотя код не очень логичный. Т.к. пользователь авторизован логичнее воспользоватся вторым способом получения пользователя.

`$tokenResult = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;`

Проблема: во втором случае не работает метод createToken(). В первом случае всё ок.
Объясните что к чему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае у Вас объект класса User а во втором Auth
У них разный набор методов.
Соответственно ->createToken() определён только в первом случае.

```
User::where
Auth::user
```

До :: это класс к которому Вы обращаетесь за статическим методом.
Поэтому если нужен ->createToken() то нужен класс User